# dose there exists continuous map from plane to unit circle?

Tags: real-analysis

Does there exists continuous serjective map from $ \mathbb{R}^2 $  onto unit circle $ \mathbb{S}^1 $?.
I feel that no such map exist. I tried normalized map but i have trouble with origin. Can anyone give some hint?

Comment: do continuous surjections preserve simple-connectivity?

Comment: yes but both are connected in my case.

Comment: $S^1$ is not *simply connected*.

Comment: but simple Connectedness doesn't preserved under continuity.

Comment: we can wrap real line around unit circle continuously.

Comment: Does $(x,y) \mapsto (\cos(2\pi xy),\sin(2\pi xy))$ work?

Comment: convinced..now i am thinking how it moves horizontal and vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention in the comments that we can wrap real line around unit circle continuously, try $(x,y) \mapsto x \mapsto (\cos x, \sin x)$.